# Issue in DateListPlot in version 12

Tags: plotting, graphics, date-and-time

We have the following example

```
Clear["Global`*"];

data = TimeSeries[{1, 2, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0, 2, 21, 15, 21, 7, 11, 5, 10, 
    18, 73, 38, 103, 21, 35, 31, 46, 31, 35, 94, 71, 48, 78, 71, 74, 
    95, 95, 56, 102, 81, 119, 99, 60, 62, 20, 77, 52, 71, 56, 72, 33, 
    31, 25, 22, 15, 17, 11, 0, 10, 156, 7, 55, 27, 16, 11, 17, 32, 10,
    15, 21}, {"Feb 26, 2020"}];

plot = DateListPlot[Accumulate[data], FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
       {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[data /@ {"FirstDate", "LastDate"}, 
       10, {"Day", "/", "Month"}] &, Automatic}}, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

When I run the above code in version 11.3, I get the correct output

[image]

However, when I run it with version 12.0, I get this one

[image]

with the error message: "A ticks specification in the value of FrameTicks should be None, Automatic, a function, or a list of ticks."

Is there a way to make the code run properly also in version 12.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove `&` from `` System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[...]& `` it works both in version 11.3 and in version 12.1:

```
DateListPlot[Accumulate[data], FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, 
       {System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[data /@ {"FirstDate", "LastDate"}, 
       10, {"Day", "/", "Month"}] , Automatic}}, Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

To get the ticks on the top frame right, you can do:

```
dticks=System`DateListPlotDump`DateTicks[data /@ {"FirstDate", "LastDate"}, 
       10, {"Day", "/", "Month"}] ;

DateListPlot[Accumulate[data], 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {dticks,dticks}},
  FrameTicksStyle->{{Automatic,Automatic},{Automatic, FontOpacity->0}},
  Mesh -> All, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

Comment: Great! But just out of curiosity, why there is a difference between the two versions?

Comment: I see an issue. The number of ticks and their positions in the upper axis do not match those of the lower axis.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z, I don't know why your original version stopped working in v12.1. I updated with a work-around for the top frame-ticks issue.